# Widget style website with resizable widgets that can be wider than one column

Tags: jquery-ui, widget

I need to create a website that works with widgets. I've found a way to create a layout like [Google IG](http://www.google.com/ig), but I also want to be able to resize widgets. It should be possible that a widget spans two columns with other smaller widgets above or beneath it. An example of what I want can be found at the [Protopage](http://www.protopage.com/) website.

In short, I want to:

```
1. Use widgets
2. Be able to resize widgets in both height and width
3. Add and remove widgets
4. Move widgets
```

If I would have documentation on how to create a website like [Protopage](http://www.protopage.com/), I'd have enough information I think.

I want to create an Azure Web Role with MVC3 using JQuery. JQuery would be the most important part for creating widgets, so is there a framework/plugin that works best for this? I've seen both [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), but they both don't show how to resize or move widgets by drag and drop. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little plugin allows them to be dragged & re-sized and they do "snap" to one another.  They don't snap to a "grid" on the page, but to each other.  https://github.com/polomoshnov/jQuery-UI-Resizable-Snap-extension  Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5xB7S/show/light/

**UPDATE:** Here is a start of one from scratch if you don't want a plug-in.  Shouldn't be too hard to create it exactly as you want from scratch.

**http://jsfiddle.net/xv57M/8/**

Here is some of the code, see fiddle for everything...

```
//CSS
#grid table{ position:absolute; width:600px; top:0px; }
#grid table td{ height:150px; width:300px; }

.item { position:absolute; width: 300px; height: 150px; background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5); }
#item1 { top:10px; }
#item2 { top:160px; }
#item3 { top:310px; }

//JS
$(function() {
    $( "#item1" ).resizable({ grid: 300 });
    $( "#item2" ).resizable({ grid: 300 });
    $( "#item3" ).resizable({ grid: 300 });

    $( "#item1" ).draggable({ grid: [ 300, 150 ] });
    $( "#item2" ).draggable({ grid: [ 300, 150 ] });
    $( "#item3" ).draggable({ grid: [ 300, 150 ] });
});
```